# Why does r.js-optimization include the require.config

Tags: javascript, optimization, requirejs

I'm playing around with r.js simplification. I have a `main.js` with my `require.config` and some code in it.

I noticed that this `require.config` called is included in the output (I disabled obfuscation).
Why is that the case, shouldn't this config be not necessary anymore?

Comment: My best guess is for async loading purposes as the shims would need a lookup hash.

Comment: the require.config call is part of main.js or it's some other file referenced in data-main attribute?

Comment: Part of my main.js. I thought it will be filtered out or something? Is there a way to reference multiple files in data-main? Like config and the entry point?